How to configure Buildroot to produce a FIT image?
how to configure buildroot to bundle uImage and rootfs and add ub header I am working with the ZynqMPSoc defconfig. Right now its just giving me a monolithic image file as well as individual components like uImage, rootfs, DTB which I provided but I want them to be bundled in a FIT image (usually called image.ub)
Thanks

You will need to create a post-build script that uses mkimage and a custom .its file. Make sure the .its file is installed in the BINARIES_DIR because that's where the binaries reside and paths are relative to the .its file.

Yes I figured it out a while ago, thanks for the response. Its pretty surprising to me that BR doesnt seem to have this option thru its config.
